# Find the length of segment in a skew quatrilateral

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be rectangle so that $|AB| = x$ and $|BC| = y$. Suppose we fold the rectangle along the diagonal $BD$ so that the planes $ABD$ and $BCD$ will be perpendicular. What is the length of $|AC|$ in the skew quadrilateral??

## Attempt:

Lets draw diagonal $AC$ and call $E$ the point where $AC$ intersects $BD$. By Pythagorean, we obtain that $|AC|= \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2}$ so that $|AE| = |EC| = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ x^2+y^2} $. As we fold the rectangle as desired, we notice that that the length of $|AC|'$ in the skew quadrilateral is the hypotenuse of triangle $AEC$. So, $|AC|' = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{4}(x^2+y^2) + \frac{1}{4}(x^2+y^2)} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sqrt{ x^2+y^2} $. So this is the desired length.

Is this a correct argument?

Comment: $AEC$ is not a right triangle, neither before nor after folding. Think of a very thin rectangle with $AD \ll AB$.

Comment: isnt the angle AEC 90 degres since we are folding the diagonal?

Comment: No. You end up with two orthogonal planes, but it doesn't mean that *all* lines in the two planes are mutually perpendicular. Again, visualize it for a very thin $ABCD$ rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: diagram]

Line segments $AE$ and $CF$ are altitudes of triangles $BAD$ and $DCB$. When the rectangle is folded as described, line segments $AE$, $EF$, and $CF$ will be edges of a rectangular cuboid with main diagonal $AC$. The length of $AC$ is given by:
$$|AC|^2=|AE|^2+|EF|^2+|CF|^2\tag{1}$$
Can you work out these lengths? Hint: The six triangles in the diagram are all similar.

Triangles $AED$ and $BAD$ are similar:
\begin{align}\frac{|AE|}{|BA|}&=\frac{|AD|}{|BD|}\\[2ex]
\frac{|AE|}{x}&=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\[2ex]
|AE|&=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\tag{2}
\end{align}
Triangles $BEA$ and $BAD$ are similar:
\begin{align}\frac{|BE|}{|BA|}&=\frac{|BA|}{|BD|}\\[2ex]
\frac{|BE|}{x}&=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\[2ex]
|BE|&=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
Triangles $AEB$ and $CFD$ are congruent:
$$|CF|=|AE|\\|DF|=|BE|$$
The diagonal $BD$ with $(3)$:
\begin{align}|BE|+|EF|+|DF|&=|BD|\\
|EF|+2\times|BE|&=|BD|\\
|EF|&=|BD|-2\times|BE|\\[2ex]
|EF|&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\[2ex]
|EF|&=\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\[2ex]
|EF|&=\frac{y^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\tag{4}
\end{align}
Combining $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(4)$:
\begin{align}|AC|^2&=|AE|^2+|EF|^2+|CF|^2\\
|AC|^2&=2\times|AE|^2+|EF|^2\\[2ex]
|AC|^2&=2\left(\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2\\[2ex]
|AC|^2&=\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{(y^2-x^2)^2}{x^2+y^2}\\[2ex]
|AC|^2&=\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\\[2ex]
|AC|^2&=\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\\[2ex]
|AC|&=\sqrt{\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}}
\end{align}

Comment: can u provide more details please thanks

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy Answer updated to include full solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Construction:- Let P be a point on BD such that $CP \bot BD$. Join AP

$\alpha = \tan ^{–1} (\dfrac {x}{y})$

Both s and t can be found.

Applying cosine law to $\triangle ADP$, z can be found.

If the paper is then folded according to the description, C’ (vertex C of ABCD) is now directly above P with $\angle \gamma = 90^0$

Then, $AC’ = \sqrt (z^2 + t^2)$

Answer (score 0):

Let the perpendicular on diagonal from a corner be $p$ and angle $ABD = \alpha$

$$ CF = AE = p= y \cos \alpha = \frac{x y }{\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}} $$

EF can be found by by equating projection of sides on diagonal

$$ 2 x \cos \alpha + EF =  \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $$

from which $$ EF= \frac{y^2-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} }$$

There are 3 mutually perpendicular line segments. Add squares of these

$$ CA^2 = 2 AE^2 + EF^2 $$

On simplification (after folding ) length of new space diagonal

$$  CA = \sqrt{\frac{x^4 + y^4}{x^2+y^2}} $$